# What if I don't call ReleaseBuffer after GetBuffer?

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings, getbuffer

From [CString to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559483/cstring-to-char), `ReleaseBuffer()` must be used after `GetBuffer()`. But why? What will happen if I don't use `ReleaseBuffer()` after `GetBuffer()`?

Can somebody show me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will cause a memory leak, but you must call `ReleaseBuffer` to ensure that the private members of `CString` are updated.  For example, `ReleaseBuffer` will update the length field of the `CString` by looking for the terminating `null` character.

Comment: @Nick, thank you. I just wrote a small program to test ReleaseBuffer(), you are right!! Thank you!

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation: "If you use the pointer returned by GetBuffer to change the string contents, you must call ReleaseBuffer before using any other CString member functions.". I.e. you don't always need to use 'em in pairs.

Comment: @SamWhan if you don't intend to change the string contents you should use a `const` pointer instead, which doesn't require `GetBuffer` - just a cast to `PCTSTR`.

Answer (score 3):

> What will happen if I don't use `ReleaseBuffer()` after `GetBuffer()`?

I haven't used MFC (and hopefully won't ever have to touch it with a ten-foot pole) but, as a rule of thumb, whenever you have an API that has both `GetXXX()` and `ReleaseXXX()` (especially when the result of `GetXXX()` conveniently is of the type that `ReleaseXXX()` takes) -- then when you forget to call `ReleaseXXX()` for every one of your `GetXXX()` calls, you will leak an `XXX`.

Comment: @sbi, thank you. From this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559483/cstring-to-char, "calling the GetBuffer method won't lead to any memory leaks. Because the destructor is going to deallocate the buffer anyway. "

Comment: @Landy: Well, there you go. So, in this case, the rule of thumb seems to fail. I guess that's why it is called a "rule of thumb", after all, no? Well, did I say I dislike MFC? Now there's one more reason to do so. An API where `GetXXX()` and `ReleaseXXX()` don't come in pairs just plain sucks...  Anyway, from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx: "After you modify the contents of a CString object directly, you must call ReleaseBuffer before you call any other CString member functions."

Comment: Thank you. MSDN says "After you modify the contents of a CString object directly, you must call ReleaseBuffer before you call any other CString member functions." But MSDN doesn't say why I *must* call ReleaseBuffer. In Nick's post, he said ReleaseBuffer() will update the length field of CString. It's a good reason I think. Thank you.

Comment: CString source code is available in atlsimplestr.h. Debugging through it, I see that CSring::ReleaseBuffre() only sets the length of the string, and doesn't do memory deallocation, allocation, or reallocation. nDataLength of CStringData (used internally by CString) holds string length. nAllocLength holds the buffer length. BufferRelase only changes nDataLength. Doesn't even touch nAllocLength . I feel this is a case of ambiguity in function name combined with terrible documentation, which MS is good at, fortunately we have the source code (unfortunately which MS can change any time).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I used `CString::GetBuffer()` and `CString::ReleaseBuffer()` :

```
LPTSTR pUnitBuffer = pAPBElement->m_strUnits.GetBuffer(APB_UNIT_SIZE);
if (pUnitBuffer != "")
{
   if (strncmp(pAPBElement->m_strUnits, (char*)pszBuffer[nLoop - nFirst], APB_UNIT_SIZE) != 0)
   {    
     LPTSTR pUnitOriginal = pAPBElement->m_strOriginal.GetBuffer(APB_UNIT_SIZE);

     strncpy(pUnitBuffer, 
            (char*)&pszBuffer[nLoop - nFirst], 
            APB_UNIT_SIZE);

     strncpy(pUnitOriginal, 
            (char*)&pszBuffer[nLoop - nFirst], 
            APB_UNIT_SIZE);

     pAPBElement->m_strOriginal.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
}
pAPBElement->m_strUnits.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not modify the contents of the CString using the pointer obtained using GetBuffer(), you do NOT need to call ReleaseBuffer() afterwards