# How to do Bitwise AND(&) on CString values in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

HI,

How to do Bitwise AND(&) on CString values in MFC(VC++)?
Example :

```
CString NASServerIP = "172.24.15.25";
CString  SystemIP = " 142.25.24.85";
CString strSubnetMask = "255.255.255.0";

int result1 = NASServerIP & strSubnetMask;
int result2 = SystemIP & strSubnetMask;

if(result1==result2)
{
    cout << "Both in Same network";
}
else
{
    cout << "not in same network";
}
```

How i can do bitwise AND on CString values ?
Its giving error as "'CString' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Peforming a bitwise-AND on two strings doesn't make a lot of sense. You need to obtain binary representations of the IP address strings, then you can perform whatever bitwise operations on them. This can be easily done by first [obtaining a `const char*` from a `CString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559483/cstring-to-char) then passing it to [the `inet_addr()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563.aspx).

A (simple) example based on your code snippet.

```
CString NASServerIP = "172.24.15.25";
CString  SystemIP = " 142.25.24.85";
CString strSubnetMask = "255.255.255.0";

// CStrings can be casted into LPCSTRs (assuming the CStrings are not Unicode)
unsigned long NASServerIPBin = inet_addr((LPCSTR)NASServerIP);
unsigned long SystemIPBin = inet_addr((LPCSTR)SystemIP);
unsigned long strSubnetMaskBin = inet_addr((LPCSTR)strSubnetMask);

// Now, do whatever is needed on the unsigned longs.
int result1 = NASServerIPBin & strSubnetMaskBin;
int result2 = SystemIPBin & strSubnetMaskBin;

if(result1==result2)
{
    cout << "Both in Same network";
}
else
{
    cout << "Not in same network";
}
```

The bytes in the `unsigned longs` are "reversed" from the string representation. For example, if your IP address string is `192.168.1.1`, the resulting binary from `inet_addr` would be `0x0101a8c0`, where:

- `0x01` = `1`
- `0x01` = `1`
- `0xa8` = `168`
- `0xc0` = `192`

This shouldn't affect your bitwise operations, however.

You of course need to include the WinSock header (`#include <windows.h>` is usually sufficient, since it includes `winsock.h`) and link against the WinSock library (`wsock32.lib` if you're including `winsock.h`).

Comment: @In silico : Pls provide some sample.

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: It should be easy to figure out based on the `inet_addr()` documentation and the Stack Overflow question/answer I linked. However, I've added a few lines.

Comment: @In silico : Using this approach i can find out whether the two IP Addresses are in same network or not ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: I woudn't suggest using `inet_addr` if it's useless for what you want to do in your question.

Comment: @In silico: Then what will be the gud approach for doing this ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: What I meant is that you can use `inet_addr()` to do what you want to do. The problem you're having in your question is that you need to obtain binary representations of the IP address strings, and `inet_addr()` can do that. Once you get the IP addresses in binary, you can then use the bitwise operations. I've edited my answer to include a usage example based on the code snippet you provided.

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: No problem. If you have another question, feel free to post it here on Stack Overflow, as long as it is specific and well-phrased.

Comment: @In silico : For Ip Address 172.24.17.174 i am getting the resulting binary from inet_addr as 2920356012.Can u pls explain how i am getting this value ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: `2920356012` is the correct decimal value for the binary form of the IP address string `172.24.17.174`. That is, `2920356012 == 0xae1118ac == 172.24.17.174`. So the conversion is in fact correct and is working.

Comment: @In silico : Yes Silico , it is right but i just want to know how we are getting this value.What is the format that is converting it this format ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: It makes more sense if you look at the IP address via hexadecimal. Each group of numbers in the IP address string represents a byte. So the IP address `172.24.17.174` is a sequence of these bytes: `172`, `24`, `17`, and `174`. Convert each byte to their hexadecimal form, and you get `0xac`, `0x18`, `0x11`, and `0xae`, respectively. If you put these four bytes together in reverse order, you get `0xae1118ac`. That is the number `2920356012` in hexadecimal.